# Cryptography - Ideas how to make it easy for the User

Tags: html, cryptography, rsa

I'm thinking about building a service like whatsapp in HTML (just to practice my skills). The idea is to encrypt the conversations in a way that is easy for an user. I thought about RSA-encryption, but than the user would have to give a password or something to a friend. What other ways are there? I never worked with encryption, so this really is more about research...

Thanks for your ideas,
stiller_leser

P.S.: I know stackoverflow doesn't like discussions too much (at least they say), but I really need a starting point :)

Comment: Read up on how TSL/SSL works

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'll do some reading. I just realized that my above question probably wasn't precise enough. I'm planning on using maybe a third party server for message transfer. So the messages will be on their servers. What I like to achieve is, that they are encrypted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate public/private key-pair at both users side, automatically. Then, the users wouldn't have to give anything to themselves physically. There are several libraries to do this, I think though.

Comment: And than transfer the public key to the communication partner? How would you do that? Wouldn't that mean, that if somebody else catches the key, they would be able to read the conversation?

Comment: A public key can only encrypt, you need the private key to decrypt, generally what happens is that person A has a public/private key pair, they give the public key to person B in the clear, Person B encrypts a symmetric key with A's public key and sends it to him and then A decrypt's the symmetric key and they both can exchange encrypted info with that symmetric key. However this alone doesn't verify that person B is who they say they are, there could be a man in the middle, you need a separate set of keys for signing/verifing too it gets complicated.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I figured it to get complicated. I decided on using crypto-js. Seems to work with a passphrase and encryption. Can't wrap my head around how to transfer the key automatically to a second user though. Guess people gonna have to remember a password for their conversation...